# Improve running time of SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table structure:

```
AdPerformance
   id
   ad_id
   impressions

Targeting
  value


AdActions
   app_starts

Ad
  id
  name
  parent_id

AdTargeting
  id
  targeting_
  ad_id

Targeting
  id
  name
  value

AdProduct
  id
  ad_id
  name
```

I need to aggregate the data by targeting with restriction to product name , so I wrote the following query:

```
 SELECT ad_performance.ad_id, targeting.value AS targeting_value, 
     sum(impressions) AS impressions, 
     sum(app_starts) AS app_starts
 FROM ad_performance
     LEFT JOIN ad on ad.id = ad_performance.ad_id
     LEFT JOIN ad_actions ON ad_performance.id = ad_actions.ad_performance_id
     RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT ad_id, value from targeting, ad_targeting 
        WHERE targeting.id = ad_targeting.id and targeting.name = 'gender' 
     ) targeting ON targeting.ad_id = ad.parent_id
WHERE ad_performance.ad_id IN 
       (SELECT ad_id FROM ad_product WHERE product = 'iphone')
GROUP BY ad_performance.ad_id, targeting_value
```

However the above query in `ANALYZE` command takes about 5s for ~1M records.

Is there a way to improve it?

I do have indexes on foreign keys

**UPDATED**

See output of ANALYZE

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=5787.28..5789.87 rows=259 width=254) (actual time=3283.763..3286.015 rows=5998 loops=1)
   Group Key: adobject_performance.ad_id, targeting.value
   Buffers: shared hit=3400223
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=241.63..5603.63 rows=8162 width=254) (actual time=10.438..2774.664 rows=839720 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=3400223
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=241.21..1590.52 rows=8162 width=250) (actual time=10.412..703.818 rows=839720 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (adobject.id = adobject_performance.ad_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=36755
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=240.78..323.35 rows=9 width=226) (actual time=10.380..20.332 rows=5998 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (ad_product.ad_id = ad.id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=190
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=128.98..188.96 rows=5998 width=4) (actual time=3.788..6.821 rows=5998 loops=1)
                           Group Key: ad_product.ad_id
                           Buffers: shared hit=39
                           ->  Seq Scan on ad_product  (cost=0.00..113.99 rows=5998 width=4) (actual time=0.011..1.726 rows=5998 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ((product)::text = 'ft2_iPhone'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                 Buffers: shared hit=39
                     ->  Hash  (cost=111.69..111.69 rows=9 width=222) (actual time=6.578..6.578 rows=5998 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 241kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=151
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=30.26..111.69 rows=9 width=222) (actual time=0.154..4.660 rows=5998 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (adobject.parent_id = adobject_targeting.ad_id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=151
                                 ->  Seq Scan on adobject  (cost=0.00..77.97 rows=897 width=8) (actual time=0.009..1.449 rows=6001 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=69
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=30.24..30.24 rows=2 width=222) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=2 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=82
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..30.24 rows=2 width=222) (actual time=0.101..0.129 rows=2 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=82
                                             ->  Seq Scan on targeting  (cost=0.00..13.88 rows=2 width=222) (actual time=0.015..0.042 rows=79 loops=1)
                                                   Filter: (name = 'age group'::targeting_name)
                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 82
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=1
                                             ->  Index Scan using advertising_targeting_pkey on adobject_targeting  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=79)
                                                   Index Cond: (id = targeting.id)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=81
               ->  Index Scan using "fki_advertising_peformance_advertising_entity_id -> advertising" on adobject_performance  (cost=0.42..89.78 rows=4081 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.046 rows=140 loops=5998)
                     Index Cond: (ad_id = ad_product.ad_id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=36565
         ->  Index Scan using facebook_advertising_actions_pkey on facebook_adobject_actions  (cost=0.42..0.48 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=839720)
               Index Cond: (ad_performance.id = ad_performance_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=3363468
 Planning time: 1.525 ms
 Execution time: 3287.324 ms
(46 rows)
```

Comment: Please share the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query.

Comment: sure, will update soon

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I just updated with the ANALYZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution plan does not seem to match the query any more (maybe you can update the query).

However, the problem now is here:

```js
->  Hash Join  (cost=30.26..111.69 rows=9 width=222)
               (actual time=0.154..4.660 rows=5998 loops=1)
      Hash Cond: (adobject.parent_id = adobject_targeting.ad_id)
      Buffers: shared hit=151
      ->  Seq Scan on adobject  (cost=0.00..77.97 rows=897 width=8)
                                (actual time=0.009..1.449 rows=6001 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=69
      ->  Hash  (cost=30.24..30.24 rows=2 width=222)
                (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=2 loops=1)
            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
            Buffers: shared hit=82
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..30.24 rows=2 width=222)
                             (actual time=0.101..0.129 rows=2 loops=1)
                  Buffers: shared hit=82
                  ->  Seq Scan on targeting  (cost=0.00..13.88 rows=2 width=222)
                                             (actual time=0.015..0.042 rows=79 loops=1)
                        Filter: (name = 'age group'::targeting_name)
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 82
                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                  ->  Index Scan using advertising_targeting_pkey on adobject_targeting
                                             (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
                                             (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=79)
                        Index Cond: (id = targeting.id)
                        Buffers: shared hit=81
```

This is a join between `adobject` and the result of

```
targeting JOIN adobject_targeting
   USING (id)
WHERE targeting.name = 'age group'
```

The latter subquery is correctly estimated to 2 rows, but PostgreSQL fails to notice that almost all rows found in `adobject` will match one of those two rows, so that the result of the join will be 6000 rather than the 9 it estimates.

This causes the optimizer to wrongly choose a nested loop join later on, where more than half of the query time is spent.

Unfortunately, since PostgreSQL doesn't have cross-table statistics, there is no way for PostgreSQL to know better.

One coarse measure is to `SET enable_nestloop=off`, but that will deteriorate the performance of the other (correctly chosen) nested loop join, so I don't know if it will be a net win.
If that helps, you could consider changing the parameter only for the duration of the query (with a transaction and `SET LOCAL`).

Maybe there is a way to rewrite the query so that a better plan can be found, but that is hard to say without knowing the exact query.

Comment: Good catch. Yes there are around 6000 records there. why would it think that there are only 18? 
unfortunately your suggestion didn't help

Comment: Does the `EXPLAIN` output change after the `ANALYZE`? If yes, please post the updated plan. Can you also post the definition of the index `fki_ad_product_id`?

Comment: CREATE INDEX "fki_ad_product_id -> product_id"
  ON ad_product
  USING btree
  (product COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

Comment: Hmmm, strange. What if you use a statistics target of 10000? Does the estimate stay the same (18)?

Comment: Quite strange. What is the data type of `ad_product.product`?

Comment: the type is enum .

Comment: That doesn't square. What PostgreSQL version is this? If it is an `ENUM`, you cannot create an index with a collation (`ERROR:  collations are not supported by type myenumtype`). Also, your index scans `(product)::text`, and that is not immutable (`ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`). Can you post the exact type definition, table definition and index definition?

Comment: postgres 9.4 you are right - the type is :
 character varying(15) NOT NULL

Comment: CREATE TABLE ad_product
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('campaign_product_seq'::regclass),
  product character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  ad_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT ad_products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT ad_product_ad_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ad_id)
      REFERENCES ad (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

Comment: Then I don't understand why no statistics are collected. Look at [this](http://rextester.com/APWLW85750) example which is similar to your case. Can you see entries in `pg_stats` for the `product` column? Try to figure out what is different in your case.

Comment: yes I get one row:
n_distinct = 1
has_most_common_vals = t
most_commong_freqs = 1
has_histogram

Comment: ok, now it looks fine, it doesn't show 18 rows, but still the time takes 3.4 seconds for retrieving 6k rows out of 1M :(

Comment: What did you change to get a better estimate? Could you share the new `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output so I can look at it?

Comment: Thanks which part of the explain? because the only thing that changed is the rows that are predicted ahead

Comment: Right. Just post he whole new plan.

Answer (score 2):

Blindly shooting here, as we have not been provided with the result of the EXPLAIN, but still, Postgres should treat this query better if you take out your `targeting` table in a CTE:

```
WITH targeting AS 
(
        SELECT ad_id, value from targeting, ad_targeting 
        WHERE targeting.id = ad_targeting.id and targeting.name = 'gender' 
)
SELECT ad_performance.ad_id, targeting.value AS targeting_value, 
     sum(impressions) AS impressions, 
     sum(app_starts) AS app_starts
FROM ad_performance
     LEFT JOIN ad on ad.id = ad_performance.ad_id
     LEFT JOIN ad_actions ON ad_performance.id = ad_actions.ad_performance_id
     RIGHT JOIN  targeting ON targeting.ad_id = ad.parent_id
WHERE ad_performance.ad_id IN 
       (SELECT ad_id FROM ad_product WHERE product = 'iphone')
GROUP BY ad_performance.ad_id, targeting_value
```

Taken from the [Documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once
>   per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
>   than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries. Thus, expensive
>   calculations that are needed in multiple places can be placed within a
>   WITH query to avoid redundant work. Another possible application is to
>   prevent unwanted multiple evaluations of functions with side-effects.

Comment: Also, consider turning the CTE into explicit join as the implicit join has been deprecated since ANSI '92. No change in performance but does in readability.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this query will solve your problem, but try it:

```
 SELECT ad_performance.ad_id, targeting.value AS targeting_value, 
     sum(impressions) AS impressions, 
     sum(app_starts) AS app_starts
 FROM ad_performance
     LEFT JOIN ad on ad.id = ad_performance.ad_id
     LEFT JOIN ad_actions ON ad_performance.id = ad_actions.ad_performance_id
     RIGHT JOIN ad_targeting on ad_targeting.ad_id = ad.parent_id
     INNER JOIN targeting on  targeting.id = ad_targeting.id and targeting.name = 'gender'   
     INNER JOIN ad_product on ad_product.ad_id = ad_performance.ad_id
WHERE ad_product.product = 'iphone'
GROUP BY ad_performance.ad_id, targeting_value
```

perhaps you would create index on all columns that you are putting in ON or WHERE conditions

Comment: That is quite a different query. a) `a RIGHT JOIN (b JOIN c)` is different from `a RIGHT JOIN b JOIN c`, and b) you get duplicate rows if there are more entries in `ad_product` with a certain `ad_id`.

Comment: yes, you're right. I'm sorry. 
The idea is eliminate the sub querys. So, if the result shows differences, you would create a CTE like the @Georgi Raychev said, and add the CTE on Right JOIN.
It's important substitute the sub select on WHERE clause too (like my query example)
I think so it's a better pratice.